Why are the initial conditions in FEUT the way they are?
The fundamental existence and uniqueness theorem for scalar linear ordinary differential equations states that for the initial value problem given by differential equation
$ \sum_{i=0}^n a_{i}(x) y^{(i)} = f,$ where $y^{(i)}$ is the $i$th derivative of $y$, and the initial conditions $y^{(i)}(x_0) = c_i$ for $i = 0$ through $ n - 1$, there exists a unique solution.
My question is, is there an intuitive explanation for why this exact combination of initial conditions has to obtain for the theorem to hold? Like if instead we were given less than $n$ initial conditions, or $n$ initial conditions that skip over a different $y^{(i)}$ than $y^{(n)}$, why does it make sense that the theorem would no longer apply?
